# Painting/Filling different sections of a shape on Illustrator CS5.1

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, fill, live-trace

I am trying to fill the inside of this JPG with different colours to represent different areas of the body; ie I want the head to be red, the arms yellow etc.

When I import the JPG into Illustrator I convert it to a vector using live trace and the image is similiar to below, however, when I look at the paths the shape is completed so that the fill is between the two lines and not in the actual image. Also, I can't figure out how to colour specific parts of the body.

Any help would be great, because, I can't figure this out!

[image: Human Body Outline]

Comment: How do you want to fill the different body parts when the image doesn't have any separation between them? You have to create those first with either lines or shapes.

Answer (score 2):

Using your supplied image, performing an image trace and expand produces a white fill shape. You can set the fill on this shape as desired. To see the other white fills around the outside it might be helpful to temporarily enable Outline view from the view menu.

To color different parts, split the fill shape using whatever method you want. The Knife Tool would work well for this quickly. Double click the fill object until you enter isolation mode so that it does not cut the black part. Another method would be to manually draw paths that you use to cut the fill apart.